# Hide horizontal scrollbar embedded google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, embed

How can I hide the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of an (iframe) embedded google spreadsheet? If there is no official way, some clever css to cut off the scrollbar would also work.

Comment: Please provide the `iframe` tag with your spreadsheet ID removed.  And whatever current CSS settings you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The horizontal scrollbar will dissapear if you specify the range of columns you want to appear:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B56....this will change according to your spreadsheet/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=0&range=A:C" width="300" height="350"></iframe>
```

Comment: source: http://hellotumo.com/2012/11/28/how-to-embed-specific-cells-when-embedding-a-google-spreadsheet/